# PnP Framework to fetch data from PowerPlatform

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, power-platform

Pnp Framework is mostly used to interact with SharePoint data, but there are methods to get Flows and Apps from PowerPlatform with PowerShell `Get-PnPPowerPlatformEnvironment` by example, but that doesn't work for me because I need to create an azure function (.net core) to work with it.  Do you know any c# library that might be of help?

Please, any guidance on this subject would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://spblog.net/post/2020/12/10/how-to-access-sharepoint-data-from-azure-function-with-spfx-and-pnp-core - Have you gone through this reference?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample C# azure function code that uses pnp framework and deployed throu vs code

```
public  class  DefaultFunctions
    {
    private  AppInfo  _appInfo;

private  readonly  IPnPContextFactory  _pnpContextFactory;
     

public  DefaultFunctions(AppInfo  appInfo, IPnPContextFactory  pnpContextFactory)

{

_appInfo = appInfo;

_pnpContextFactory = pnpContextFactory;

}

  

[FunctionName("GetLists")]

public  async  Task<IActionResult> Run(

[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "GetLists")] HttpRequestMessage  request, ILogger  log)

{

var  query = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();

var  siteUrl = query["siteUrl"];

var  tenantId = query["tenantId"];

var  clientSecret = new  SecureString();

     
foreach (char  c  in  _appInfo.ClientSecret) clientSecret.AppendChar(c);

 

var  onBehalfAuthProvider = new  OnBehalfOfAuthenticationProvider(_appInfo.ClientId, tenantId, clientSecret, () =>  request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter);

var  results = new  List<ListData>();

  

using (var  pnpContext = await  _pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync(new  System.Uri(siteUrl), onBehalfAuthProvider))

{

var  lists = pnpContext.Web.Lists.Load(l  =>  l.Id, l  =>  l.Title).ToList();

  

foreach (var  list  in  lists)

{

results.Add(new  ListData { Title = list.Title });

}

}
        
return  new  JsonResult(results);

}

}
```

For complete information you can refer the [SharePoint data from azure function.](https://spblog.net/post/2020/12/10/how-to-access-sharepoint-data-from-azure-function-with-spfx-and-pnp-core)